# Uso, significato e spelling di "bimbominchia"

Tags: word-meaning, etymology, spelling, neologism

Il neologismo "bimobominchia o bimbominkia" sembra aver preso piede e, almeno per quel che mi riguarda, lo sento usare sempre più spesso in riferimento adolescenti viziati.

Ci sono varie definizioni in rete come la seguente da [www.linkuaggio.com](http://www.linkuaggio.com/2013/01/definizione-di-bimbominkia-sgrammatica.html): ***Bimbominkia***:

> - parlano quasi con monosillabi, e scrivono usando abbreviazioni che spesso sono davvero difficili da comprendere, adottando questo loro stile in SMS, chat e in ogni tipo di forum; abbellendo sempre il tutto con un numero spropositato con tante faccine per esprimere le loro emozioni.

Trattandosi di un neologismo il significato  e lo spelling sono probabilmente ancora in via di definizione, comunque:

> Qual è la  definizione più comumenete accettata?
>
> Qual è  lo spelling o gli spelling più comunemente usati?
>
> Chi ha coniato questa espressione?

Comment: Grazie, Gio, anche a me piacerebbe avere più lumi sull'uso e l'origine del termine. Do qui qualche link a chi voglia unirli con altro materiale per costruire una risposta: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bimbominkia_(Neologismi)/, http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bimbominkia, http://nonciclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Bimbominkia (scherzoso, ma fra le righe anche istruttivo), più la voce dello Zingarelli 2017, non liberamente accessibile: [segue]

Comment: bimbomìnkia / bimboˈminkja/

[comp. di bimbo e minchia nel sign. 2 ☼ 2007]

s. m. (f. bimbamìnkia, pl. m. bimbimìnkia, pl. f. bimbemìnkia)

● (Internet) adolescente che comunica attraverso i social network un'immagine trasgressiva di sé, usando nella scrittura quasi esclusivamente abbreviazioni ed emoticon

Comment: Trovo che sia di gran lunga prevalente la grafia “bimbominkia”, comunque.

Comment: la definizione della Treccani è sicuramente la più completa. Sulle origini del neologismo, credo che sia una storpiatura dispregiativa di "Bimbomix" (serie di dischi degli anni '80 non di sicuro caratterizzati da spessore musicale)

Answer (score 2):

In questo [articolo](https://n3rdcore.it/la-storia-del-termine-bimbominchia/) vengono spiegate la nascita e la diffusione  di bimbominchia.
L'articolo spiega che il termine nacque su Manicomio, un forum creato all’interno di NGI. L'utente più famoso era Lord Phobos e sarebbe stato proprio lui a scrivere per la prima volta la parola “bimbominchia” per insultare un altro utente.

Comment: Potresti espandere il tuo post per rispondere alle domande dell'OP? Penso che potresti farlo usando il contenuto dell'articolo che hai citato. Innanzitutto, ["link-only answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/262998) non sono considerate buone risposte su Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

La scelta della k invece del ch sta a sottolineare la parodia di una delle scelte di scrittura di un "bimbominkia" fornendogli un rafforzativo che nel tempo lo ha fatto diventare la forma prevalente.
L'utilizzo in internet può essere affibbiato ad una persona sia per il suo modo di scrivere tipico degli SMS, quindi tutto abbreviato:

- Comunque = cmq
- Tutto = tt
- Quando = qnd
- Quanto = qnt
- ecc.

sia per il comportamento infantile che dimostrano di avere.
Ha una connotazione fortemente negativa.

Comment: Davide, grazie per la tua risposta, ma permetti un'osservazione. Qui non c'è problema a *menzionare* il turpiloquio (se per esempio dovessi spiegare l'etimologia di “cazzotto”), ma non è molto ben accetto *usarlo*...

Comment: @DaG in fondo ha solo fatto la traduzione letterale, lasciamoli il beneficio del dubbio. Comunque alla lista manca la quintessenza del bimbominkia: *xkè*!

Comment: I see your point, @N74, but even if the topic were, say, “what does *testa di minchia* mean?” paraphrasing it as *testa di cazzo* rather than defining or explaining it wouldn't be in my opinion a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @DaG ti do ragione ma non vedo il modo di spiegare il significato senza utilizzare il turpiloquio. Se hai una idea migliore sei libero di editare la mia risposta che a ben vedere può essere identificata come inappropriata.

Comment: @DavidePaselli, "La scelta della k invece del ch sta a sottolineare la parodia di una delle scelte di scrittura di un "bimbominkia" fornendogli un rafforzativo che nel tempo lo ha fatto diventare la forma prevalente. " dove lo hai letto? Parodia? Rafforzativo? Puoi essere piú specifico aldilá di personali sensazioni...  Secondo treccani: <<Composto dal s. m. bimbo e dal s. m. minchia, con sostituzione connotativa, in senso spreg., del grafema c con il grafema k. >>. E poi, "bimbo del cazzo" significa/é "bimbominkia"?

Comment: @DavidePaselli,  Al tuo "ma non vedo il modo di spiegare il significato senza utilizzare il turpiloquio" dico "se dovevi spiegarlo ad un bimbo usavi il turpiloquio? Se non sai usare altro che turpiloquio in contesti come questi mi domando dove non lo usi."